# Match if visible on 70% with getBoundingClientRect JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the following result with `getBoundingClientRect()`?

Now with the current function bellow it matches when 100% of an element width is inside viewport.

```
function viewport_check(e) {

var ep = e.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (ep.left >= 0 && ep.right <= ($(e).outerWidth() || $(window).width())); 
}
```

I need to to it matches on percentage based value, like in this case I want to get match if element inside viewport on 70%, and not match if it visible only for 30%. How it can be done?

// My tryings:

```
return ((ep.left+30) >= 0 && (ep.right-30) <= ($(e).outerWidth() || $(window).width()));
```

Comment: This is what `Intersection Observers` are for. One of the parameters you pass to it is `threshold` which is a percentage of the element is in the viewport. 
I would advise you polyfill it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a method to calculate the area given a boundingclientrect:

```
function calcArea(rect){
    return (rect.right-rect.left) * (rect.bottom-rect.top)
}
```

Then to determine the bounds of a rect inside the viewport:

```
function clipRect(rect){
    return {
        left: Math.max(0, rect.left),
        top: Math.max(0, rect.top),
        right: Math.min(window.innerWidth, rect.right),
        bottom: Math.min(window.innerHeight, rect.bottom)
    }
}
```

And to put it togther simply divide the area of the clipped rect by the area of the unclipped rect:

```
function calcOcclusion(element){
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
    var clipped_rect = clipRect(rect)
    return Math.max(0, calcArea(clipped_rect)/calcArea(rect))
}
```

so:

```
console.log(Math.round(calcOcclusion(document.querySelector('#myElement'))*100),'% visible')
```

```js
function clipRect(rect){
 return {
  left: Math.max(0, rect.left),
  top: Math.max(0, rect.top),
  right: Math.min(window.innerWidth, rect.right),
  bottom: Math.min(window.innerHeight, rect.bottom)
 }
}

function calcArea(rect){
 return (rect.right-rect.left) * (rect.bottom-rect.top)
}

function calcOcclusion(element){
 var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
 var clipped_rect = clipRect(rect)
 return Math.max(0, calcArea(clipped_rect)/calcArea(rect))
}


var elem = document.querySelector('#myElement')
window.onscroll = function(){
  elem.innerHTML = "I'm "+Math.round(calcOcclusion(elem)*100)+"% visible"
}
```

```css
body{
  padding: 200px 0;
}

div{
  padding: 50px 20px 200px 20px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="myElement">
Scroll me
</div>
```